# Import folder of modules in Python

Tags: python, module, import

Is it possible in python to get a list of modules from a folder/package and import them?

I would like to be able to do this from a function inside a class, so that the entire class has access to them (possibly done from the `__init__` method).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are `from package import *` and `dir(package)` insufficient? Note that `dir` is a Python command, as well as a command line one.

Comment: @Hannele Does that really work for you? I get `['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']` without any mention of the modules in `package`. `dir` shows the modules if the modules themselves are explicitly imported, though, but that defeats the purpose of the question.

Comment: I might have to double-check how that works with a folder - do you have an `__init__.py` file in the folder? Even empty, this is what tells python to treat the folder as a module.

Comment: Yes, I had an `__init__.py`. What I didn't have is what @MarkHildreth helpfully referenced: the line `__all__ = ['bar','baz']` in `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [modules document](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

> The only solution is for the package author to provide an explicit
>   index of the package. The import statement uses the following
>   convention: if a package’s `__init__.py` code defines a list named
>   `__all__`, it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when from package import * is encountered. It is up to the
>   package author to keep this list up-to-date when a new version of the
>   package is released. Package authors may also decide not to support
>   it, if they don’t see a use for importing * from their package. For
>   example, the file sounds/effects/`__init__.py` could contain the
>   following code:
>
> ```
> __all__ = ["echo", "surround", "reverse"]
> ```
>
> This would mean that from sound.effects import * would import the three named submodules of the sound package.

Yes, you could find a way to do this by doing a directory listing for the files in the directory and import them manually. But there isn't built-in syntax for what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can know the list of the modules with the dir function

```
import module
dir (module)
```

Later in a program, you can import a single function :

```
from module import function
```

Comment: When I try `dir(foo)` (with `foo` being a package) I get `['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']` which doesn't contain a list of the modules in the package.

Comment: @EricWilson `>>> type(dir(sys))
<type 'list'>`

Comment: This won't get you the list of modules. This will get you the list of attributes for the package (as defined in the `__init__.py` file of the package's directory). The modules for the package are only included in this list if they are explicitly stated in the `__all__` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `distribute` module provides a mechanism that does much of this.  First, you might start by listing the python files in a package using `pkg_resources.resource_listdir`:

```
>>> module_names = set(os.path.splitext(r)[0] 
...     for r
...     in pkg_resources.resource_listdir("sqlalchemy", "/")
...     if os.path.splitext(r)[1] in ('.py', '.pyc', '.pyo', '')
...     ) - set(('__init__',))
>>> module_names
set(['engine', 'util', 'exc', 'pool', 'processors', 'interfaces', 
'databases', 'ext', 'topological', 'queue', 'test', 'connectors',
'orm', 'log', 'dialects', 'sql', 'types',  'schema'])
```

You could then import each module in a loop:

```
modules = {}
for module in module_names:
    modules[module] = __import__('.'.join('sqlalchemy', module))
```